# WPF PropertyChanged Notification from Application to Window

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have an Application that opens a Window based on some events. When the Window is loaded I bind MyClass to some controls. This binding is working fine but I’m not getting PropertyChanged notifications.

MyClass implements INotifyPropertyChanged. MyClass is updated periodically in the Application but my Window’s reference to MyClass is not seeing the change.

How can I get MyClass to refresh in the Window after my Application changes MyClass?

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var res = (MyResource)Application.Current.FindResource("MyRes");
        var cntx = (MyContext)res.DataContext;
        MyClassProp = cntx.MyClass;
        MyClassProp.PropertyChanged += MyClassProp_PropertyChanged; // Not being triggered
    }
```

Also tried...

```
cntx.MyClass.PropertyChanged += MyClass_PropertyChanged; // Not triggered
```

Comment: We can't deduce anything from the code you've posted.

Comment: Q:  "How can I get MyClass to refresh in the Window after my Application changes MyClass?"  
A: MVVM